# Problem with understanding Ninject Binding/Injection

Tags: ioc-container, ninject

In my MVC project, I have setup my MvcApplication_start() :

```
ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(new NinjectControllerFactory());
```

And have successfully bound an .To regarding my IProductsRepository to MySqlProductsRepository:

```
public class NinjectControllerFactory : DefaultControllerFactory
{
    private readonly IKernel _kernel = new StandardKernel(new MyServices());

    protected override IController GetControllerInstance(System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType)
    {
        if (controllerType == null)
            return null;
        return (IController) _kernel.Get(controllerType);
    }

    public class MyServices: NinjectModule
    {
        public override void Load()
        {

            Bind<IProductsRepository>().To<MySqlProductsRepository>();
        }
    }
}
```

But I am using NHibernate, and have a separate Session Factory class that has a GetSession() method that returns an ISession.

```
public static ISessionFactory SessionFactory = CreateSessionFactory();

    private static ISessionFactory CreateSessionFactory()
    {
        var cfg = new Configuration().Configure(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "nhibernate.config"));
        cfg.SetProperty(NHibernate.Cfg.Environment.ConnectionStringName, System.Environment.MachineName);
        NHibernateProfiler.Initialize();
        return cfg.BuildSessionFactory();
    }

    public static ISession GetSession()
    {
        return SessionFactory.GetCurrentSession();
    }
```

I wanted to set it up so that my MySqlProductsRepository would be passed and ISession object by Ninject when it was created:

```
public class MySqlProductsRepository : IProductsRepository
{
    private readonly ISession _session;

    public MySqlProductsRepository(ISession session)
    {
        _session = session;
    }
```

And my Controller would be handed a IProductsRepository instance:

```
 public class AdminController : Controller
{
    private readonly IProductsRepository _productsRepository;

    public AdminController(IProductsRepository productsRepository)
    {
        _productsRepository = productsRepository;
    }
```

MY PROBLEM:

I can't seem to figure out in my IoC container where I bind my IProductsRepository to my Repository, how to register an ISession, how to hand an ISession to my MyProductsRepository object when it is created, and hand an MyProductsRepository object to my Controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a couple of blog post I wrote that explain how to use Ninject in and ASP.NET MVC application. The application in the blog post uses the same technologies that you are using: Ninject, NHibernate, and MySql. I also am using a repository pattern. There are a lot of parallels between what you are doing and these posts.

http://blog.bobcravens.com/2010/07/using-nhibernate-in-asp-net-mvc/

http://blog.bobcravens.com/2010/06/the-repository-pattern-with-linq-to-fluent-nhibernate-and-mysql/

http://blog.bobcravens.com/2010/09/the-repository-pattern-part-2/

http://blog.bobcravens.com/2010/11/using-ninject-to-manage-critical-resources/

Take a look. If you have questions, feel free to contact me.

Comment: +1 fantastic stuff - Fills a gap in the market - this deserves to become a FAQ answer to this sort of question here!

Comment: Thanks Bob, perfect, going to start reading them now, should be a major help.